# Undefined method rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Why am I getting an undefined method error whenever I use this block of code:

`<%= @user_infos.website %>`

But works when I use the each loop?

```
<% @user_infos.each do |user| %>
   <%= user.website %>
<% end %>
```

UserInfos controller:

```
class UserInfosController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user_info, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def index
    @user_infos = UserInfo.all
    respond_with(@user_infos)
  end

  def show
    respond_with(@user_info)
  end

  def new
    @user_info = current_user.user_infos.build
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @user_info = current_user.user_infos.build(user_info_params)
    @user_info.save
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def update
    @user_info.update(user_info_params)
    respond_with(@user_info)
  end

  def destroy
    @user_info.destroy
    respond_with(@user_info)
  end

  private
    def set_user_info
      @user_info = UserInfo.find(params[:id])
    end

    def user_info_params
      params.require(:user_info).permit(:website, :location)
    end
end
```

Home controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @questions = Question.all.order("created_at desc")
  end

  def profile
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @answer = Answer.all.order("created_at")
    @questions = Question.all.order("created_at")
    @user_info = UserInfo.new
    @user_infos = UserInfo.all.order("created_at desc")
  end
end
```

My intentions is not to loop but just simply display the uer's information inside the profile view. Looping is causing double paragraphs and that is surely not how I want it.

Comment: That is because @user_infos is an Array of @user_info instances. The Array does not have a method `website`, the instances do though.

Answer (score 1):

`@user_infos` is a **collection of records**, not a **single record**. So you just can't use `<%= @user_infos.website %>` which gives you `undefined method` error.

Answer (score 0):

```
@user_infos = UserInfo.all.order("created_at desc")
```

gives you all UserInfo's so you can't use

```
<%= @user_infos.website %>
```

and if you are opposed to writing a loop yourself you can just use map to get all the websites in an array

```
<%= @user_infos.map(&:website) %>
```